# sin and cos functions showing error outputs (c++)

Tags: c++, dev-c++

When I tried to print sin() and cos() of 60 degrees, 30 degrees,s, and 45 degrees in a for loop, for some iterations, the output is showing strange values in the range of e-006.
I am using DevC++ to run the code.
Why this happens and how can I rectify this?
A screenshot of the output is attached with this. The error occurs only once in every 100-200 iterations.

[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjKOu.png)
compiler settings:
[compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T8J9.jpg)[image: compiler settings 1][image: compiler settings2][image: compiler settings3][image: compiler settings4][image: compiler settings5][image: compiler settings6]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     for(double i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<"  :  "<<cos((M_PI/180.0)*60.0)<<"  :  "<<cos((M_PI/180.0)*45.0)<<"  :  "<<sin((M_PI/180.0)*45.0)<<"  :  "<<sin((M_PI/180.0)*30.0)<<"\n";
    }
}
```

```
The output is like:
i    cos(60)   cos(45)     sin(45)     sin(30)
**********************************************
0  :  0.5  :  0.707107  :  0.707107  :  0.5
1  :  0.5  :  0.707107  :  0.707107  :  0.5
2  :  0.5  :  0.707107  :  0.707107  :  0.5
3  :  0.5  :  0.707107  :  0.707107  :  0.5
4  :  0.5  :  0.707107  :  0.707107  :  0.5
5  :  7.62939e-006  :  0.707107  :  0.707107  :  0.5
6  :  0.5  :  0.707107  :  0.707107  :  0.5
7  :  0.5  :  0.707107  :  0.707107  :  0.5
8  :  0.5  :  0.707107  :  0.707107  :  0.5
```

Thank you.

Comment: cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/oMhvdcsr8. Apart from `i` you are printing the same values on each iteration.

Comment: which compiler are you using? What compiler flags?

Comment: Yes, I am printing the same values, so the output should be the same. But for some iterations, the output is showing different values..

Comment: I can not reproduce the error, too.

Comment: Is it possible that your processor is busted? I don't know, maybe one of the floating point registers is broken and outputs rubbish, or something like that?

Comment: Each time when i run it, error happens at different i values

Comment: dev-c++ is just an ide. It doesnt help to diagnose the problem. Also `sin` and `cos` are not generally broken. Please tell us what compiler you are using and what compiler flags.

Comment: I am adding a screen image of compiler settings

Comment: Cannot reproduce on 3 different platforms.

Comment: You are not showing the compiler flags. I don't know c-dev++ but you probably should show us the Settings tab

Comment: I am also not able to reproduce the same output, each time it gives error at different points. When i am running it online, no issues

Comment: Out of interest, does it ever fail for `cos(61)`? Does it ever fail if you use an `int` for the counter? What if you use `std::cerr` rather than `std::cout`? To me it looks like something in your toolchain is busted.

Comment: I also can't reproduce the error.

Comment: It does fail for cos(61) also. Tried using int for counter, std::cerr. But still it shows the error

Comment: My guess is also a compiler, operating system, or CPU bug. The code should be fine!

Comment: Not the compiler, clearly. If not a fried chip, electrical interference, perhaps? (wild guess)

Comment: There may be some issue with my laptop. I tried the code on another pc with devC++. No issue there. But I dont understand whats the issue with my lap.